# General J2EE architecture for Wizard/Questionnaire type of applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms

If you are designing an application such that the user must answer several questions on a page and there are dozens of pages.  What Java libraries and tools do you use and are there any other recommendations that helped you to write such a site.

Requirements:

- User must be able to quit application at any time and return
- User must be able to navigate from start to finish based on previous questions

Possible Notes and Potential Issues:
  - Use of Struts2+ or some other j2ee framework
  - Possible use of spring core
  - User of hibernate
  - Oracle backend

- Do you save to the database on each page?
- Optional (use of JMS) to queue that a page has been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring Webflow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow) is good at this kind of thing and I'd use it in this situation since I'm already using it for other purposes. It might me a little heavy to pick up if you haven't used it before and this is the only (immediate) use you have for it.

A "form" object in webflow can contain the data from multiple forms split across many pages, and each page fills in only a part of the whole object.

To quit and return any time you'd have to persist the form object at each page/transition. I'd lean toward saving it in the same table as finished forms but have a column for complete=false and a last activity timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of a temporary datastore (like a staging table) is required to capture the user activities state due to the requirement -

> User must be able to quit application
>   at any time and return

You can capture all the user action in a relevant value object (say, named `WizardData`) in your `HTTPSession` (since you are using web tier). There is no need to save the data on each page. Instead, update `WizardData` in session on "next" or "previous". Once the user finishes the wizard activity, save the information to your database tables ( j2ee/spring/hibernate ).

But if the user does not finish the activity(logs out or navigates away), you may retain the `WizardData` in session until the user logs out or the session becomes invalid. In either of those cases, persist the `WizardData` to a staging table with userid as the key. Thus, you can retrieve the wizard stage once the user logs back in or logs in and starts the wizard back.

IMHO, using JMS will be an over kill to implement a functionality as this. You do not gain any implementation ease while you add additional layer and complexity.